# Which element do I need to modify to add padding between a drawable and its enclosed elements?

Tags: android-linearlayout, android-drawable, xml-drawable, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

Based on what I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770071/how-can-i-enclose-some-xml-elements-in-a-bounding-box/23776368), I was able to add some "fences" around groupings of related widgets:

[image]

But, as you can see, the second/lower box is crowding the first radio button text. Which element do I need to modify to add some space? Do I need to add something to the box itself, which lives in the drawable folder and is defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
    >
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#f000"
    />
</shape>
```

...or to the inner LinearLayout, or to the radio button in question (or its enclosing RadioButtonGroup widget)? Here is that xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/box"
    android:orientation="vertical">

. . .

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radbtnBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/using_labels_black" />

. . .

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, you can add some **padding**, which will result in som **inner space** added

Comment: To the box drawable, or...???

Comment: In the box. I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add some **padding**, which will result in som **inner space** added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <padding
        android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"
    />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#f000"
    />
</shape>
```

Feel free to experiment different values other than 4dp (even different for top/bottom, left/right sides)